# SpreadSheet cell auto fill with value of another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I need a script that autofills a cell with the values of a cell in the same row, but in a different (but fixed) column.

I have tried this script, but I can't get it to write the Value of anything but the cell itself.

```
function onEdit(event) {
   var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
   var range = event.source.getActiveRange();
   if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Tweet" && range.getColumn() == 2 && range.getValue().toString().trim() !== "" && range.getValue().indexOf("http:") != 0) {
       range.setValue("http://test.com/" + range.getValue());
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    function onEdit(event) {
       var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
       var range = event.source.getActiveRange();
       var fixed_column = 6; //Substitute this to your fixed column number.
       if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Tweet" && range.getColumn() == 2 && range.getValue().toString().trim() !== "" && range.getValue().indexOf("http:") != 0) {
           range.setValue("http://test.com/" + sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),fixed_column).getValue());
       }
}
```

Just substitute the number of your fixed column.

Comment: Very useful. However I want to get the Value from Column6 and write that in Column 2 when I edit Column 2. This code takes the Value from Column 2 when I edit Column 2 and add the final result to Column 6.

Comment: Check my Edited answer. I didn't know what the test.com part is for, but I kept it just in case.